# How does a server verify a client in a mulitplayer game?

Tags: security, authentication, ssl, multiplayer

So tons of games are run via custom clients (call it game.exe) but must communicate to a server. How does the developer ensure that only connections from the custom client are accepted and not any other requests, say from a web browser?

Ex: I play game.exe and my requests go thought no problem. 
 I then submit a request to that game server using my web browser or some other POST utility, but it is ignored by the game server to prevent cheating.

Is this done via secret strings that are coded into game.exe and sent with every request? It seems to vulnerable to intercept them with a packet sniffer. Same applies with a client-side SSL certificate, someone could easily find the key file in the game files and forge requests.

Answer (score 1):

Typically games that are stand alone applications - with a .exe extension on Windows, for example - do not use http as their protocols, unlike web browsers.

Irrespective of the protocol used, however, games typically send credentials - often account credentials, similar to a user name and password - when the connection is established.  Many games uses a persistent TCP connection, so this only had to be done when logging in to the game.

Comment: so someone could fake being the game client by sending forged requests as long as they knew their own credentials? I guess that's why most games have an authoritative server setup.